# Open bookmark list in new tab using chrome 38

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarks

I usually surf with multiple tabs open.

There is a new fancy version of Chrome-android, (38.0.2125.102 and later), and with it disappeared the possibility of seeing the bookmarks list when opening a new tab. Now it always defaults to a google search box, a google logo, and some icons displaying often-surfed-to web pages. If I wish to view my bookmarks I have to click the tab for bookmarks at the bottom of the screen. How can I make it quicker to open bookmarks again?

### Solutions I've discarded

- "Ok, so just open the bookmarks list directly then?"

I would, but the bookmarks list opens in the active tab, not in a new one. So that only works if I wish to replace the current page, which is seldom the case.

- "It's just one more click, it can't be that bad?"

The number of clicks has increased by a factor of 1.33, that is not insignificant for an action that is taken very often. But worse, it breaks my flow when surfing.

- "Switch to Firefox?"

I have. I don't like the font scaling in that browser. Still, it's my fallback for now.

- "Undo the chrome upgrade, stay at version 37."

Insecure, and really hard to do after-the-fact. You can uninstall all updates, but then, depending on OS version, you go back all the way to 32. That is not good.

## tl;dr:

How can I open one of my bookmarks in a new tab with as few clicks as possible using Android Chrome 38+?
Before 38 it was 3 clicks. Now it is 4. A minor issue one might think, but tell that to my muscle memory.